# Foreman Command Not Found Despite Having Package

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, foreman, env

I am trying to use `foreman` with my NodeJS project to run my ENV variable keys, but for some reason, despite have the foreman package installed and appearing in my `node_modules` I am having an issue trying to run `foreman start`. The error message is `-bash: foreman: command not found`. Any thoughts to why this is happening? If I run foreman start, will this run the application and allow access to anything within my `.env` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the foreman readme you should be using 'nf start' to run it.